# Proving $f(x)=x^2$ is monotone

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove $f(x)=x^2$ is a monotonic decreasing or increasing function

For $x\ge 0:\forall x,y\in\mathbb R:x,y\ge0 :x\le y \Rightarrow f(x)\le f(y)$

So $x\le y \Rightarrow x^2\le yx \le y^2 \Rightarrow f(x)=x^2\le y^2= f(y)$.

But now I don't get how to do it for $x\le 0$, I understand that because $x\le y$ are negatives then by "rising their power" the 'less then' should flip but how do I show it?

Comment: It isn’t: $-1<0<1$, but $f(-1)>f(0)<f(1)$, so $f$ is neither monotone increasing nor monotone decreasing. (It’s monotone increasing on $[0,\to)$ and monotone decreasing on $(\leftarrow,0]$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott aren't we supposed to divide it to cases where it increases and where it decreases?

Comment: If it does both, it’s not monotone over its whole domain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Check $f'(x)=2x$, since it dont changes of sign for $x>0$ is monotone there, and if $x<0$ it doesnt change of sign, so is monotone there but not in all domain.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$-2\le-1$$ but $$(-2)^2\ge(-1)^2.$$

Recall that multiplying an inequality by a negative flips the direction.

---

Now a proof that the function $x^2$ is not monotonic:

$$-1<0<1$$ but $$(-1)^2>0^2\land 0^2<1^2.$$